# Field template for display mode

Tags: theming, 8

I have a template for my field: `field--field-category.html.twig`. Is there a way to override this for a specific Display Mode? A have a mode called `teaser block`. I tried `field--teaser-block--field-category.html.twig` as well as a couple of other formats.

I know I can modify how the field is output in `node--teaser-block.html.twig` but I'd like to do it at the field template level.

Comment: Best thing is to enable Twig template debugging and devel Kint and formulate your hook from that. [I wrote a post related to this recently.](http://dannyenglander.com/blog/drupal-8-theming-tutorial-how-craft-custom-theme-hook-suggestions-and-templates)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the field template there is by default no suggestion with the specific display mode.

You can add this suggestion in a hook:

```
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_field_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  $suggestions[] = 'field__' . 
    $variables['element']['#field_name'] . '__' . 
    $variables['element']['#view_mode'];
}
```

Put this into MYTHEME.theme in the theme directory.

Comment: Good stuff. But I think to stick with D8's naming convention, you should really make it `$suggestions[] = 'field__node__' . $variables['element']['#field_name'] . '__' . $variables['element']['#bundle'] . '__' . $variables['element']['#view_mode'];`