# How to check for view mode in twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

We have one field (field_tabs) that is used on Basic and Article content type. On the Basic page content type, it has a custom view mode (view_mode_vertical) and on the Article content type it has a different custom view mode (view_mode_horizontal).

Basic Page (default view mode) Manage Display

- field_tabs (view mode = view_mode_vertical)
- title
- body

Article (default view Mode) Manage Display

- field_tabs (view mode = view_mode_horizontal)
- title
- body

In a [field.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21classy%21templates%21field%21field.html.twig/8.5.x), how can we detect the view mode?

Our two options we explored was either a [node template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21templates%21node.html.twig/8.4.x) or field template (we went with field). We would like to do this in a way that we only need add the logic for detecting the view_mode in one place. In case we add a third or fourth view_mode, we can simply add another elseif (or switch case) to the code.

Sample Twig code we were looking for:

```
{% if view_mode == 'view_mode_vertical' %}
  <div class="tabs__vertical">...</div>
{% else %}
  <div class="tabs__horizontal">...</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: IMO its easier to just make the view mode twig suggestions in that case. I don't like having one file with a ton of conditional logic in it for display.

Comment: @Kevin so something like `node--basic--view-mode-vertical.html twig`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In a field.html.twig, how can we detect the view mode?

In a field template there is no top level variable for the view mode like in the node template. You can create one and then your twig code should work:

```
{% set view_mode = element['#view_mode'] %}
```

Another option is to add a template name suggestion, see [Field template for display mode](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201210/field-template-for-display-mode).

Both are valid options. There are many projects heavily depending on Twig logic while other projects prefer PHP in preprocess and template name suggestion hooks.

Comment: the field template for display mode did the job.

Comment: Thanks! But I think it must be: elements['#view_mode']! Also interesting for this part is :  {% for key, value in _context  %}
      {{ key }}
    {% endfor %} to geht all given variables!

Comment: @Bruno, a field has usually `element` as render element. You are referring to a different template probably.