# Field template for display mode of referenced paragraph

Tags: 8, theming

I have a custom field `field_platform` (referencing a the custom paragraph type `platform`) and a template for my field: `field--field-platform.html.twig`. Is there a way to override this for a specific display mode of the referenced paragraph type? I have a mode named `cover_view` for the custom paragraph type `platform` I want to override the field template for.

I found [Field template for display mode](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201210/field-template-for-display-mode) but the template suggestion is for the display mode of the content, not the referenced paragraph.

Drupal 8.5.6, Paragraphs 8.x-1.3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [`hook_theme_suggestions_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x) like in the other answer and you can find everything you need in the `$variables`.

---

The following snippet will add the template suggestion for the view mode of the referenced paragraphs. Note that this will probably only make sense as long as you use *only one* paragraph type OR all multiple paragraph types have the same view mode configured.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_field_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  $element = $variables['element'];

  if ($element['#field_type'] == 'entity_reference_revisions') {

    foreach ($element as $key => $value) {
      if (is_numeric($key) && isset($value['#paragraph'])) {

        $paragraph = $value;
        $suggestions[] = 'field__' . $element['#field_name'] . '__paragraph__' . $paragraph['#view_mode'];
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Seems you can implement that from you theme's `*.theme` file as well.

---

I guess the same logic works for any entity (node etc.) reference as well.